# Comparing complex and real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

In learning Laplace transform I got sucked into the Bromwich integral, and I tried to evaluate one like a regular integral and it didn't work. Then I realized complex integration is quite different. Is it, and if so how, do the CONCEPTS differ from those in real analysis relating to integrals and derivatives. What stopped me from taking this integral?

I tried searches related to differences in complex and real analysis (specifically regarding integration) and didn't find anything targeting this in particular. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Complex integration, in my experience, is just so far apart from your typical real integration that it'd be hard to explain in one post. I think, fundamentally, you can imagine it as basically how contour/line integrals work in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but with a sort of "complex flavoring," many nuances specific to complex numbers.

Comment: @Eevee Trainer Could you elaborate on complex flavouring a bit. Is there a general idea behind what changes about the calculus and why (in terms of what analysis actually is)?

Comment: The concepts are not really any different, but the techniques are entirely different.  This is because the assumption that a complex-valued function of a complex variable is differentiable turns out to be much stronger than in the real case.  It automatically has derivatives of all orders, for example.  Many powerful theorems result.

Comment: @saulspatz oh, ok. But what specifically didn't let me take it like a normal integral? From what I've explored derivatives seem to be pretty similar.

Comment: I can't answer that.  I don't know what the integral was, or what you did.  You don't generally evaluate complex integrals with antiderivatives.

Comment: @saulspatz thanks, why aren't they evaluated using antiderivatives? Is it just uncommon or it doesn't work? Knowing the Laplace transform of 1 is 1/s, I put it back into the Bromwich integral hoping to get 1. I used real analysis methods and got something super weird instead that totally failed in everyway I tried it.